# Multiple logical buffers in one real frame buffer

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I have a number of modules that must process a video stream in real time. The simple approach would be to have a frame buffer, from where the modules take the video images, process, and then remove them.

Problem #1: Not all the modules work at the same speed. Some are able to process all the frames, some not. So, some modules will not process all the frames. If I wait for all the modules to finish the job before removing a buffer, the faster ones will stall with no reason (**Figure A**).

A simple solution would be **Figure B**. A separate buffer for each module. If the buffer is full, frames will not be placed there. But Problem #2 arises: Memory is wasted: Some frames will have multiple copies in different buffers.

A smarter solution would be one physical buffer, with more logical buffer attached, like in **Fig C**. A frame is added in the real buffer when at least one logical buffer can accommodate it, and a real buffer is deleted when all the logical buffers that link to it are removed. (A simple implementation solution is given by smart pointers - Add a smart pointer to the buffer to all the logical buffers that can accommodate it) Problem #3: It may happen, in the worst case, that each frame is assigned to a module, and instead of sharing, it will be a messy draw-back to Solution B.

**Question**

Is there a better way to deal with this problem? A standard answer? A template library implementing it?

**Edit** 
This somehow complicated mechanism to use buffers, but remove frames if the buffer is full, offers a scalable solution on different platforms: I process as many frames as possible, regardless of the modules or hardware performance.

[image]

Comment: Why do you have queues if the system is designed to fail (modules that are designed not to be able to keep up with the full rate)? You need to define how you want the system to work if there isn't time for all modules to finish.

Comment: The time spent processing each frame is not constant, even in the same module. Having a short queue (2-3 frames) allows me to cover fluctuations in processing time without losing too many frames. But if the processing speed is low on average, it should be able to automatically skip some frames.

Comment: maybe I wasn't clear enough: I want each module to process as many frames as possible, without *a priori* knowledge on each module's performances

Comment: What should skip frames? The problem is, if you have a module that takes an arbitrarily long time to process a frame buffer, that module owns it until it's finished. So you run out of buffers and have to stall the input until you have freed one.

Comment: Ok, important info: Modules do not depend on each other output, so there is no reason to wait for one processing unit before grabbing a new frame in a different module.

Comment: This is an interesting problem and is the kind of thing I have experience with designing, but too much discussion and questions needed for stackoverflow format I think. Maybe someone else will have a great idea.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9494/discussion-between-blueshift-and-vasile)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two methods I have seen in production real-time video systems:

1. Similar to option A, store a single list of buffers, but add two sets of flags to each buffer.  The first set of flags specifies which tasks need to be performed on the buffer, and the second set of flags specify which tasks have been performed.  When each module is ready it will scan the list of buffers until it finds one that it can help with.
2. Similar to option C, use multiple fifos containing pointers to the actual frame data.  Use [reference counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) to keep track of which frames are still live.  This means that every time you make a new pointer to the frame you call a function to increment its reference count, and every time you have finished with the pointer you call a function to decrement the reference count.  Frames can be reused once their reference count reaches zero.

In my opinion, the first method is simpler to implement and is fine if you have a small number of outstanding frames and a small number of processing tasks, but the second is more general and should be easier to scale to a more complicated system.